# opening connection and reading stream

Tags: java, exception, web-crawler

I get a runtime error when I try to do "http://www.oracle.com". It says, `error java.net.UnknnownHostException:www.oracle.com` then it lists a whole bunch of errors having to do with Sockets, HttpURLConnection  etc. and it all ends up pointing at this connect method, specifically `InputStream steam` line.

Here is my code:

```
   public void connect (String website) throws IOException {

     URL u = new URL(website);
     URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
     InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
     Scanner input = new Scanner(stream);
     input.useDelimiter("<a");
     readWebsite(input);

  }
```

Comment: After running your code...I did not find any issues by passing "http:// www.oracle.com/" to connect() method. The UnknownHostException occurs when you cannot find the host, perhaps you should check with the internet connection. Try pinging oracle.com on a command prompt and if successful, then run your program to see if the error is occurring again.

Comment: @SanthoshGutta we had a power outage, and this caused my issue. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting by IP address:

```
URL u = new URL("http://23.56.70.140");
```